# ReportViewer Print When Pressed "Enter" in C#

Tags: c#-2.0, reportviewer

I have a reportviewer and have enabled print button but not enabled toolbar.When user press enter reportviewer should start printing.It should not show even printdialog also.What code should i write in KeyPres event ?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/9f52d79d-5baf-4e84-97d5-7dbba6623b89) is what worked for me when I wanted to programmatically print from ReportViewer.

You'll want to set the PrintController to StandardPrintController to suppress the print dialog, e.g.

```
printDoc.PrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for manual printing in Report Viewer.  It's in VB.NET though.
It works by handling the Print Event of your PrintDocument object.

```
  Dim m_pageSettings As PageSettings          'Stores page settings for printout
  Dim m_currentPage As Integer                'Used for index of pages
  Private m_pages As New List(Of Stream)()    'Stores a stream for each pages

  'Event fires when printDocument starts printing - reset page index to zero
  Private Sub PrintDocument1_BeginPrint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.BeginPrint
    m_currentPage = 0
  End Sub

  'Function that prints all the pages included in the report
  Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim pageToPrint As Stream = m_pages(m_currentPage)
    pageToPrint.Position = 0

    Dim pageMetaFile As Metafile = New Metafile(pageToPrint)      'create an image(metafile) of the report page
    Using (pageMetaFile)
      'Create a rectangle the size of our report - include margins
      ' Dim adjustedRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle( _
      '    e.PageBounds.Left - CType(e.PageSettings.HardMarginX, Integer), _
      '    e.PageBounds.Top - CType(e.PageSettings.HardMarginY, Integer), _
      '    e.PageBounds.Width, _
      '    e.PageBounds.Height)

      Dim adjustedRect As Rectangle = New Rectangle( _
    e.PageBounds.Left, _
    e.PageBounds.Top, _
    e.PageBounds.Width, _
    e.PageBounds.Height)

      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect)   'Fill rectangle with WHITE background
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageMetaFile, adjustedRect)        'Draw report in rectangle - this will be printed
      m_currentPage = m_currentPage + 1
      e.HasMorePages = m_currentPage < m_pages.Count          'If more pages are left - keep processing
    End Using
  End Sub

  'Event fires when PrintDocument queries for PageSettings.  Return a copy of m_pagesettings.
  Private Sub PrintDocument1_QueryPageSettings(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.QueryPageSettingsEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.QueryPageSettings
    e.PageSettings = CType(m_pageSettings.Clone, PageSettings)
  End Sub

  'Render the report in a EMF - This function creates metafiles(images) of each page in the report
  Private Sub RenderAllLocalReportPages(ByVal localReport As LocalReport)
    Dim deviceInfo As String = CreateEMFDeviceInfo()    'Enhanced MetaFile
    Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing
    localReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, AddressOf LocalReportCreateStreamCallback, warnings)
  End Sub

  'Callback function used with RenderAllLocalReportPages
  Private Function LocalReportCreateStreamCallback(ByVal name As String, ByVal extension As String, ByVal encoding As Encoding, ByVal mimeType As String, ByVal willSeek As Boolean) As Stream
    Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
    m_pages.Add(stream)
    Return stream
  End Function

  Private Function CreateEMFDeviceInfo() As String
    Dim paperSize As PaperSize = m_pageSettings.PaperSize
    Dim margins As Margins = m_pageSettings.Margins

    'The device info string defines the page range to print as well as the size of the page.
    'A start and end page of 0 means generate all pages.
    Return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>emf</OutputFormat><StartPage>0</StartPage><EndPage>0</EndPage><MarginTop>{0}</MarginTop><MarginLeft>{1}</MarginLeft><MarginRight>{2}</MarginRight><MarginBottom>{3}</MarginBottom><PageHeight>{4}</PageHeight><PageWidth>{5}</PageWidth></DeviceInfo>", ToInches(margins.Top), ToInches(margins.Left), ToInches(margins.Right), ToInches(margins.Bottom), ToInches(paperSize.Height), ToInches(paperSize.Width))
  End Function

  'Convert report printing size to inches
  Private Shared Function ToInches(ByVal hundrethsOfInch As Integer) As String
    Dim inches As Double = hundrethsOfInch / 100.0R
    Return inches.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) & "in"
  End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using custom reporting for my project. Custom means the report that is built using e.Graphics.DrawString type code.

So I made All the report(coding) in the default printing event of `PrintDocument`

Here is the  of the PrintDocument Tool. Drag and Drop it on your screen and then double click on it to create the event handler.

The code behind event handler of `PrintDocoument` is:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
       Image image = Properties.Resources.New_Header;
       Font font = new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold);
        Font font2  = new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular);
        float fontHeight = font2.GetHeight();
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 20, 5, 260, 130);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Date:" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 160));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Invoice#:  "+InvoiceNoTextBox.Text, new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(160, 160));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Client Name:  " + ClientNameTextBox.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 180));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("______________________________",
            new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 190));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Product", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(23, 220));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("U/Price", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(170, 220));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Qty", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(210, 220));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(240, 220));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("______________________________",
           new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 220));

        int CurrentX = 25;
        int CurrentY = 230;
        int offset = 20;
        foreach (var i in shoppingCart)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(i.ItemName, new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(CurrentX, CurrentY+offset));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(i.UnitPrice.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(180, CurrentY + offset));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(i.Quantity.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(215, CurrentY + offset));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(i.TotalPrice.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(240, CurrentY + offset));
            offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;

        }
        CurrentY = CurrentY+offset;
        e.Graphics.DrawString("______________________________",
          new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, CurrentY-5));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Total Amt: Rs." + TotalAmountTextBox.Text, new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(180, CurrentY + 35));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Discount%:  " + DiscountTextBox.Text.Trim()+"%", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(180, CurrentY + 50));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Discount: Rs." + JustDiscountTextBox.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(180, CurrentY + 65));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Grand Total: Rs." + TotalToPayTextBox.Text, new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(180, CurrentY + 80));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Advance: Rs." + AdvancePaymentTextBox.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, CurrentY + 95));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Cash: Rs." + givenCash.Text.Trim(), new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(180, CurrentY + 95));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Pending: Rs." + PendingPaymentTextBox.Text, new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, CurrentY + 110));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Return: Rs." + ReturnTextBox.Text, new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(180, CurrentY + 110));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Software Provided By Muhammad Abbas", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, CurrentY + 125));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Mob:0304-9550308", new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, CurrentY + 140));

    }

    private void PrintPreviewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

And Finally the **Answer** of you Question. Use this in  your Form `KeyDown` event.

```
    private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }
```

It will Directly print your receipt from your Printer.